# replace double decimal (..) in ediText with single decimal (.)

Tags: android, decimal

I want to replace the value in an editText if user enter two decimal points by mistake

```
 else if(txtLdays.getText().toString().trim().contains(".."))
             {


                txtLdays.requestFocus();    
                txtLdays.setError("Double decimal ?");  

             // something like this
               ??   txtLdays.replaceWith(".." , ".");

                 return false;
             }
```

Comment: there is no replaceWith for textview.

Comment: and what if he enters four dots ?

Comment: no i have restricted the user to enter only one value after decimal

Comment: Have you tried as `txtLdays.setText(txtLdays.getText().toString().replace(".." , "."));`  ?also consider  blackbelt comment

Comment: thanks got it.. txtLdays.setText(txtLdays.getText().toString().replace(".." , "."));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`String#replaceAll()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and match the `.` more than one times in the string.

```
 txtLdays.setText(txtLdays.getText().toString().replaceAll("([\\.]{2,})", "."));
```

Comment: `replaceAll` is method of String instead of EditText or TextView